# Внедрить Coyote Time в скрипт godot 4.1

Tags: разработка-игр, godot

> Пробовал разные способы внедрить Coyote Time в игру, но видимо не понял логику.

> Время койота, иногда называемое “кадрами койота”, - это невидимая функция, которая дает игроку небольшое дополнительное окно для совершения решающего прыжка, как при взлете, так и при приземлении.

> Результат: у игрока есть шанс прыгнуть после того как он окажется в воздухе

````
const SPEED = 120.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0


@onready var anim = $AnimatedSprite2D


var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    
    if not is_on_floor() : 
        
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
        if direction:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
            
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and is_on_floor()  :
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        anim.play("jump")
        
    if direction:
        if velocity.y == 0:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
            anim.play("walk")

    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        if velocity.y == 0:
            anim.play("idle")
            
            
        
    
    if direction == -1:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = true
    elif direction == 1:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = false
        
    if velocity.y > 0:
        anim.play("fall")

    move_and_slide()
    ```
````

Comment: Добавьте больше подробностей в вопрос, что именно вы имеете в виду под фразой «Coyote Time» и какой результат вы ожидаете от внедрения?

Answer (score 0):

> Я решил проблему, пришлось переставить условия прыжка и передвижения и поработать с таймером который включается после того как игрок покидает поверхность

```
extends CharacterBody2D


const SPEED = 120.0
const JUMP_VELOCITY = -400.0


@onready var anim = $AnimatedSprite2D
@onready var coyote_timer = $CoyoteTimer


var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Input.get_axis("ui_left", "ui_right")
    var was_on_floor = is_on_floor()
    
    if direction:
        if velocity.y == 0:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
            anim.play("walk")

    else:
        velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, SPEED)
        if velocity.y == 0:
            anim.play("idle")
    
    if was_on_floor && !is_on_floor():
        coyote_timer.start()
            
            
    if not is_on_floor() : 
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
        if direction:
            velocity.x = direction * SPEED
            
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept") and (is_on_floor() || coyote_timer.is_stopped())  :
        velocity.y = JUMP_VELOCITY
        anim.play("jump")
        
    
    
    if direction == -1:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = true
    elif direction == 1:
        $AnimatedSprite2D.flip_h = false
        
    if velocity.y > 0:
        anim.play("fall")

    move_and_slide()
```